# Populating labels from dataset with linq

Tags: c#, linq, object, dataset, label

I'm writing a point of sale application for my family business. I have a MS sql server dataset loaded from a database with three tables as data source. I'm trying to populate some label objects from the dataset with the code blow.  No errors on compile, but when the form is loaded the labels remain empty.

```
    private void frmAccounts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBDataSet ds = new DBDataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Account"];

        var query = from act in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where act.Field<int>("AccountID") == 1
            select new
            {
                FirstName = act.Field<string>("FName"),
                LastName = act.Field<string>("LName")
            };

        foreach (var account in query)
        {
            lblName.Text = account.FirstName + " " + account.LastName;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
var query = from act in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where act.Field<int>("AccountID").Equals(1)
```

can you inspect "query" object? Is it properly filled with data?